# value not set in my model on selection of combo box Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have created custom model for my report.Here i have declared two variables fy_yr and fy_qtr.In my report form ,i have two combo boxes and I have to generate my report according to values from my combo boxes.But my problem is the selected values from combos are not set in my custom model.What is the problem?
My report view code:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'member-report',
    'action' => ['member-report'],
    'method' => 'post',
]); ?>
<table border="1" class="table-bordered">

    <tr>
        <td style="margin-right:20px;">  

            <?= $form->field($model, 'fy_yr')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(FiscalYear::getAllFiscalYr(),'fy_id','fiscal_yr'),
            ['prompt'=>'Select Fiscal Year.']
         )
        ?>
        </td>

        <td>  

            <?= $form->field($model, 'fy_qtr')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(CodeValue::getFiscalYrQuater(),'cv_id','cv_lbl'),
            ['prompt'=>'Select Quarter.']
         )
        ?>
        </td>

    <td><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Print" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flatb"/></td>       
    </tr>

</table>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My model is:

```
 class SfclReport extends Model
   {
   public $fy_yr;
   public $fy_qtr;

   public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fy_id', 'fy_qtr'], 'required'],

        ];
    }


}
```

and my controller is

```
 public function actionMemberReport()
{   

        $model =  new SfclReport;

      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {


    }
     return $this->render('member_report',['model'=>$model]);
}
```

Comment: As you are using $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) no need of again define  $model->attributes=$_POST['SfclReport'];..

Comment: is  fy_yr ,  fy_qtr not in table column

Comment: yes fy_yr ,fy_qtr are not table fields

Answer (score 1):

add fy_yr and Specify your variable datatype

```
class SfclReport extends Model
    {
   public $fy_yr;
   public $fy_qtr;

   public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fy_id', 'fy_qtr'], 'required'],
            [['fy_id',], 'integer'],
            [['fy_yr','fy_qtr'], 'string'],

        ];
    }


}
```